# Should you query Google Maps API directly or through your own REST API?

Tags: reactjs, spring, google-maps-api-3

As the title explains I want to query `Google Maps API` based on a user input. Now, for the sake of clarity I've got a system in place with the frontend built in `React` and the backend on `Java Spring`. In particular, I want to perform forward geocoding whenever a user presses `submit` on a form to search for an address. Should I just do this natively inside the React code or create a `service` for it inside the Spring backend?

My thoughts would be that by chaining API calls would add unnecessary complexity but at the same time I don't feel like mixing responsibilities and making some part of the code call my own API and some other part ignore it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make direct calls to Google Maps API from your frontend, you will expose your API key to frontend. Anyone could grab your API key and make queries to Google API outside of your application so  unless you are sure that you can secure your api keys, i would suggest making api calls from your backend.